# Get an animated rigid body object affected by the rigid body world speed (Slow-motion)

Tags: animation, physics, rigid-body-simulation

I have an destruction animation with particles, rigid bodies and smoke. Now I want at some point all the animations and simulations be in slow motion.
This works all fine, **BUT** my "destroyer rigid body" is an animated rigid body - **this is because I want this object to be on a excact location at the end of the animation.**

I know i can animate the "animated" option on the rigid body just before it collides, but then the object will just destroy and then fall down. But the end position of the destroyer object should be higher than in the beginning..

I also could just slow down the animation of the destroyer object, but this would lead to a wrong destruction animation.
I hope you understand what i mean..

[image: my problem...]
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Another way is to slow down the whole animation, or change the fps to 120 (to make a 25% slow-motion)... but the render time would be enormeous!

Comment: nobody any idea?